# How to completely disable header from/to/cc modifications aka Masquerade in Sendmail?

Tags: sendmail

I am running sendmail 8.15 on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server that is relaying emails from other internal and external mailservers and relays their emails as a smarthost to the internet. Even if some header fields may not be RFC compliant, I want to relay those emails without any modifications of the header adresses.

Problem: Sendmail by default **always** masquerades header-from, header-to and header-cc addresses and replaces empty domains and localhost with its own FQDN.

Original email headers when delivering at port 25:

```
From: me
To: me@localhost
```

Email headers after passing sendmail:

```
From: me@myhost.mydomain.com
To: me@myhost.mydomain.com
```

Expected headers after passing sendmail:

```
From: me
To: me@localhost
```

What I have tried before in my sendmail.mc:

- FEATURE(limited_masquerade): seems to not change anything
- MASQUERADE_AS(`example.org'): results in missing domains getting replaced by me@example.org, but localhost still gets replaced by the servers FQDN
- MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`myhost.mydomain.com'): in my understanding, this should make sendmail to not masquerade anything except  'myhost.mydomain.com', but that din't help either.

Is there any way to completely disable the masquerade feature of sendmail?

It would be also okay, to set some random config values, such that  missing domains and 'me@localhost' will not be touched.

Comment: I am running an up-to-date version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: no-domain and localhost are special.  Sendmail rewrites them to valid-on-other-hosts form.  Does sendmail rewrite address with valid domains?

Comment: No, other valid domains are not getting rewritten. The problem only exists with the two special cases no-domain and localhost.